# How to remove all tablelayout inside scrollview in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created a dynamic `tableLayout` inside `scrollview1`. I have a function that needs to clear all the `tablelayout`. And  the `tablelayout` has dynamic buttons too. How do I list all `tablelayout` inside `scrollview` *and* remove it? Maybe by using a `getchild` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove child views from an Android view by calling `removeAllViews()`.

For example, if you want to clear your `scrollview1`:

```
scrollview1.removeAllViews();
```